# Shall I use sizeof(DEFINED_CHAR_ARRAY)?

Tags: c, string, sizeof

I'm not ANSI C or C++ expert, please forgive me if this question is silly.

I'm working on modem response parser and I have char array (string?) definitions like this:

```
#define MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_OK "OK\n"
#define MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_CME_ERROR "+CME ERR"
#define MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_CMS_ERROR "+CMS ERR"
#define MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_ERROR "ERROR"
#define MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_PB_DONE "PB DONE"
#define MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_CALL_READY "CALL READY"
#define MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_CONNECT "CONNECT "
```

This is how I want to use it (to avoid hardcoded lenghts):

```
// received line starts with ERROR
if ( strncmp(MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_ERROR, (const char *)MODEM_UART_rxbuf, sizeof(MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_ERROR)) == 0) {
    (*async_task_complete_hnd)(ERROR, NULL);
} 

//    else if ...

MODEM_UART_rxbuf_clear(); // safe memset all bytes to 0
```

But code above was not working in some cases. I changed everything like this (`5` instead of `sizeof(MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_ERROR)`) and now everything works.

```
// received line starts with ERROR
if (strncmp(MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_ERROR, (const char *)MODEM_UART_rxbuf, 5) == 0
) {
    (*async_task_complete_hnd)(ERROR, NULL);
} 

//    else if ...

MODEM_UART_rxbuf_clear(); // safe memset all bytes to 0
```

---

**QUESTION**

**Did I messed up something elsewhere in my code?**

`sizeof("Some text")` should always return 9 (as I expect)?

`sizeof("Some text\n")` should always return 10 (as I expect)?

Comment: `sizeof(MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_ERROR)` is the size of the pointer, not the length of the string, which is `strlen(MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_ERROR)`

Comment: @WeatherVane Nah, it should be the size of the array.

Comment: `sizeof("Some text")` is `10` rather than `9`, you forgot to count the null terminator. And `sizeof("Some text\n") == 11`. You could've just printed the `sizeof` return values.

Comment: @WeatherVane no it gives the length of the string literal array (including terminating null char) https://godbolt.org/z/b84qPs

Comment: @P__J__ thank you but that was already said, which I checked out myself. One should still be wary of using `sizeof` with arrays, wich *may* be pointers in the context.

Comment: @WeatherVane **`sizeof(MODEM_AT_RESPONSE_ERROR) is the size of the pointer`** am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you missed the following dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string literal such as

```
"Some text"
```

always include an implicit *extra* character, `\0` ( or `NULL` )
which in turn will always result in a count of the visible characters *+1*.

So

```
sizeof("Some text")
```

*"should always return 9 (as I expect)?"*  No, it will be 10

```
sizeof("Some text\n")
```

*"should always return 10 (as I expect)?"*  No, it will be 11

The [sizeof macro](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=sizeof+macro), counts *all* of the bytes that comprise *any* variable, such as a [char array](https://www.studytonight.com/c/string-and-character-array.php) or a [string literal](https://riptutorial.com/c/example/1086/string-literals), including the terminating `\0` (`NULL`) byte.
Note that this behavior stands in contrast to the [strlen()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) function where it *uses* the terminating `NULL` byte to know when to *stop* counting but does not include it in the total byte count.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` of the string literal returns number of the elements of the string literal including the terminating null character

https://godbolt.org/z/b84qPs